# Trend in results for reproducibility of iron and phosphate

Tags: water

Periodically in our lab, we have a reproducibility test for the various samples that we analyze. One such sample is boiler water. Two of the parameters that we test are phosphate in boiler water and iron in boiler water. Random error aside (shaking of sample, measurement bias, etc.), why are my iron results usually lower than the original and my phosphate is usually higher? Is there any chemical basis for these trends?

Comment: Is your boiler water treated with phosphates?